# Sphinx match by first letter

Tags: mysql, sphinx, sphinxql

I need simple explanation of why my queries fail to bring the results i need.

Sphinx 2.0.8-id64-release (r3831)
Here is what i have in sphinx.conf:

```
SELECT
trackid,
title,
artistname,
SUBSTRING(REPLACE(TRIM(`artist_name`), 'the ', ''),1,3) AS artistname_init
....

sql_field_string = title
sql_field_string = artistname
sql_field_string = artistname_init
```

Additional settings:

```
docinfo = extern
charset_type = utf-8
min_prefix_len = 1
enable_star = 1
expand_keywords= 0
charset_table = U+FF10..U+FF19->0..9, 0..9, U+FF41..U+FF5A->a..z,  U+FF21..U+FF3A->a..z, A..Z->a..z, a..z
```

Query works. I index my data without problems. However i am failing to make sphinx bring any sensible results. I am using SphinxQL to query.

Example:

```
select
artistname, artistname_init from myindex
WHERE MATCH('@artistname_init ^t*')
GROUP BY artistname ORDER BY artistname_init ASC limit 0,10;
```

brings nothing related to the query.
I've tried everything i could think of like:

```
MATCH('@artistname_init ^t*')
MATCH('@artistname_init[1] t')
MATCH('@artistname_init ^t$')
```

Can anyone please point where is my mistake and perhaps give me query that will work for my case?
My target is to get results that follow this sorting order:

```
B (Single letter)
B-T (Single letter + non-alphabet sign after)
B as Blue (Single letter + space after)
Baccara (First letter of single word)
Bad Religion (First letter of several words)
The B (not counting "The ")
The B.Y.Z (Single letter + non-alphabet sign after not counting "The ")
The B 2 B (Single letter + space after not counting "The ")
The Boyzz (First letter of single word not counting "The ")
The Blue Boy (First letter of several words not counting "The ")
```

Or close to it.

Comment: Do you really have a column called `artistname` and a column called `artist_name` in your database? Perhaps they contain different information? Also what are your min_prefix_len, min_infix_len, min_word_len, enable_star and dict settings?

Comment: the source query is actually several joins and it's really big. I just simplified it for this case and I overlooked the field names. The 2 fields that needs attention are the artistname and artistname_init, the rest is not really related to my case. artistname holds artist names, the init field hold first 3 letters of the name after removing "The " if exists. I will update the question with the requested information.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of moving parts in what you're trying to do, but I can at least answer the title portion of it. Sphinx offers [field-level ranking factors](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#field-factors) to let you customize the WEIGHT() function – it should be much easier to order the matches the way you want, rather than trying to actually filter out entries that matched the query later than the 1st or 2nd word.

Here's an example, which will return all results with a word starting with "b", sorted by how early that word appears:

```
SELECT id, artistname, WEIGHT()
FROM myindex
WHERE MATCH('(@artistname (b*))')
ORDER BY WEIGHT() DESC 
LIMIT 10 
OPTION ranker=expr('sum(100 - min_hit_pos)');
```

If you want to filter out other cases like "Several other words then B", I think I'd suggest doing that in your application. For example, if the fourth result has the keyword in the 3rd word, only return the first 3 results. That, or actually create a new field in Sphinx *without* the leading "The", and then add a numeric attribute to the index to show that a word was removed (you can use numeric attributes in your ranker expressions).

As for ranking "B-t" more highly than "Bat", I'm not sure if that's possible without somehow changing Sphinx's concept of alphabetical order.. You could try diving into the source code? ;)

---

One last note. For this particular kind of query, MySQL (I say MySQL because it's the common way of sourcing a Sphinx index) may actually work just as well. If you strip the leading "The", a B-tree index (which MySQL uses) is a perfectly good way of searching if you're sure you only want results where the query matches the beginning of the field. Sphinx's inverted indexes are kind of overkill for that sort of thing.